# Problems with subsetting survey design

Tags: r, subset, survey

I am using IBGE's PNS microdata from Brazil (it can be obtained here: https://ww2.ibge.gov.br/home/estatistica/populacao/pns/2013/default_microdados.shtm)

I created some new variables using the existing ones in the database and afterwards I used the code below to create a survey design.

```
pes_all_des <-
  survey::svydesign(
    id = ~ upa_pns ,
    strata = ~ v0024 , 
    data = base , 
    weights = ~ pre_pes_full , 
    nest = TRUE
  )

post_pop_all <- unique( base[ , c( 'v00283.y' , 'v00282.y' ) ] )

names( post_pop_all ) <- c( "v00283.y" , "Freq" )

match.design <- survey::postStratify( pes_all_des , ~ v00283.y , post_pop_all )
```

If I try to run a regression using `svyglm()` with this survey design, I get a "normal" result, with no warnings.

Now I will subset this design:

```
match.design2 <- subset(match.design, d_match==1)
```

Running the same regression using `svyglm()` I get a warning message:

```
1: In summary.glm(g) :
  observations with zero weight not used for calculating dispersion
2: In summary.glm(glm.object) :
  observations with zero weight not used for calculating dispersion
```

What does this message mean actually? It doesn't block me from running the regression, So I don't know how much should I be concerned about it.

Just for more information, if a do a summary() in both designs I get quite different results:

```
summary(match.design)
Stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (6062) clusters.
survey::postStratify(pes_all_des, ~v00283.y, post_pop_all)
Probabilities:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0000733 0.0008510 0.0018686 0.0033423 0.0036237 0.1058348 

> summary(match.design2)
Stratified 1 - level Cluster Sampling design (with replacement)
With (6062) clusters.
subset(match.design, d_match == 1)
Probabilities:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0001152       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf
```

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks in advance!

Wagner

Comment: Could multicollinearity be causing this?

Comment: I don't think so, @RomanLuštrik. As you can see, there is some issue with the subsetting process. The regression shows those warnings no matter what variables I use.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is a result of the fact that the `survey` package is trying to help you avoid making a statistical mistake.

For especially complex designs involving calibration/post-stratification/raking, estimates for sub-populations (in this case `subset(match.design, d_match == 1)`) can't simply be computed by filtering away data from outside of the sub-population of interest; that approach [produces misleading standard errors and confidence intervals.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8659480)

So to keep you from running into this *statistical* issue, the `survey` package doesn't let you completely remove records outside of your subset of interest. Instead, it essentially takes note of which rows you want to ignore and then adjusts the probability weights to be effectively zero. See this SO question: [Why do attempts to filter/subset a raked survey design object fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55387266/5373794)

The way that a weight of zero is implemented is by updating the values of the weights stored in `match.design2$prob` (a numeric vector of case weights). Entries in that vector which correspond to removed rows in the data are changed to `Inf` (confusingly, `Inf` denotes a weight of zero).

That's why you see the following summary of the weights in the output you included:

```
Probabilities:
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
0.0001152       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf       Inf
```

I'm not sure if this raises an issue with the use of `svy.glm`.